# Get and compare values in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I'm quite new to ASP.NET and jQuery. Having a problem with queries in MVC 4. I want to compare a previously generated value (Id) by jquery with a database table. All rows that match with the value (Id) queried in the previous function should be displayed. So

This is the function in Controller to get the rows I want to compare with:

```
 public PartialViewResult NumberByAnimal(int? animalId) {

          object numbers = null;
          numbers = db.Inhabitants.Find(animalId);

          return PartialView("Number", numbers);
    }
```

This is a part of the previous process that contains the value (animalId) through an AJAX search I want to compare with the table 'Inhabitant' in database:

```
   $('#search').keyup(function () {
var searchField = $('#search').val();
var myExp = new RegExp(searchField, 'i');

$.getJSON("/Animal/GetAnimals", function (data) {
    var output = '<ul class="searchresult">';

        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            if (val.name.search(myExp) != -1) {
                output += '<li class="listobject">';
                output += '<div class="list">' + val.name + '</div>';
                output += '<p class="listelement">Order: ' + val.order + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Family: ' + val.family + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Genus: ' + val.genus + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Species: ' + val.species + '</p>';
                output += '<div id="add" class="hidden">';
                output += '<div class="ctry-view">';
                output += '<p class="listelement">Origin: ' + val.origin + '</p>';
                output += '<p class="listelement">Continent: ' + val.continent + '</p>';
                output += '</div>';
                output += '<img class="img-view" alt="Picture normally displayed" src="data:image/jpeg;base64," + val.image />';
                output += '<p class="desc">' + val.shortDescription + '</p>';
                output += '</div>';
                output += '<hr>';
                output += '</li>';

                         }
```

And then I want to pass the id to the function and create the Partial view but $(this).val() returns 0. I don't know how to get the animalId of the clicked object.

```
 $(document).on("click", "li.listobject", function () {
$("ul.searchresult").remove();
$('#map-canvas').removeAttr('class');
var currentId = $(this).val();

alert(currentId);
$('#numberPlaceholder').load("/Inhabitant/NumberByAnimal", { animalId:currentId });
```

The partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<TheMenagerieNetwork.Models.Inhabitant>

 <ul>
  @foreach (var item in Model) { 
   <li>
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.number)
   </li>
  }
 </ul>
```

It throws a Null Reference Exception!
Thanks for any help!

Comment: please show the complete code inside the getJson without breaking them into parts.

Comment: Please note that [tag:model-view-controller] is intended for questions about the *pattern*. You don't need it (and shouldn't include it anyway) since you've already tagged this with the asp.net-mvc-4 tag.

Comment: I think I might go for another approach by loading partial views with jQuery.

Comment: Where is your `Animals\GetAnimals` method? Did you override the routing? Your `$.getJSON()` function is obviously looking for JSON, but the MVC action method you showed is returning a partial view.

Comment: The GetAnimals method is in the AnimalController, NumberByAnimal method in the InhabitantController. No, I didn't override the routing, is it necessary? The image isn't displayed either. So the search provides results for animals. If you click one of them, related values from the Inhabitant model shall be displayed.